# Possible to share same model/data between QListview and a QTreeview?

Tags: qt, listview, treeview, models, pyside

Say my data looks like:

```
Record:
   type - string  #formatted ISO date/time string
   ctime - string #actually just a unix timestamp
   source - string
   data- string
```

Serving the list view, the model's data method looks like:

```
def data(self, index, role):
    record = self.contents[index.row()]
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return "%s: %s - %s" % ( record['source'], record['data'], record['time'], )
```

As for the tree view, the actual body would be rendered the same, but the first line of tree node's would pivot on Record.type.   Looking at def data's signature, I am assuming I can possibly just pivot from the role or would I need to go one more step back in abstraction and have a core model manage the data and then proxy to list & tree models?

Taking an additional step back, is there any good/concise sources of documentation on how QT's ( pySide ) data layer works?  This could possibly be another question, but it would likely lead to the answer to this question as well so I put it here.

Comment: There is demonstration in QT_INSTALL_PATH/demo/interview. It share model between QListView, QTreeView and QTableView.